# Same iterator object yields different result in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across a very strange behaviour in Python.
Using a class derived from `UserDict`, the iterator `a.items()` behaves differently in a for loop than `a.data.items()`, even though the two are **identical**:

```
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 17 2013, 22:32:14) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datastruct import QueueDict
>>> a=QueueDict(maxsize=1700)
>>> for i in range(1000):
...     a[str(i)]=1/(i+1)
... 
>>> a.items()
ItemsView(OrderedDict([('991', 0.0010080645161290322), ('992', 0.0010070493454179255), ('993', 0.001006036217303823), ('994', 0.0010050251256281408), ('995', 0.001004016064257028), ('996', 0.0010030090270812437), ('997', 0.001002004008016032), ('998', 0.001001001001001001), ('999', 0.001)]))
>>> a.data.items()
ItemsView(OrderedDict([('991', 0.0010080645161290322), ('992', 0.0010070493454179255), ('993', 0.001006036217303823), ('994', 0.0010050251256281408), ('995', 0.001004016064257028), ('996', 0.0010030090270812437), ('997', 0.001002004008016032), ('998', 0.001001001001001001), ('999', 0.001)]))
>>> a.items()==a.data.items()
True
>>> # nevertheless:
... 
>>> for item in a.items(): print(item)
... 
('992', 0.0010070493454179255)
>>> for item in a.data.items(): print(item)
... 
('993', 0.001006036217303823)
('994', 0.0010050251256281408)
('995', 0.001004016064257028)
('996', 0.0010030090270812437)
('997', 0.001002004008016032)
('998', 0.001001001001001001)
('999', 0.001)
('991', 0.0010080645161290322)
('992', 0.0010070493454179255)
>>>
```

The class definition is as follows:

```
import collections, sys

class QueueDict(collections.UserDict):

    def __init__(self, maxsize=1*((2**10)**2), *args, **kwargs ):
        self._maxsize=maxsize
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.data=collections.OrderedDict(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self.data.move_to_end(key)
        return super().__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        self._purge()

    def _purge(self):
        while sys.getsizeof(self.data) > self._maxsize:
            self.data.popitem(last=False)
```

This is quite disturbing. Any ideas how the same object [by "visual" inspection, and also by `(a.items()==a.data.items()) == True`] can, and why it does, behave differently in the for loop?

Thanks for your help and ideas!

Comment: What exactly is the difference you are seeing here?

Comment: Exactly what is the difference between using the two objects in a for loop?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: the first only iteratoes over the first element, the second over all!

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought the `...` was because you had snipped the rest of the iteration.

Comment: No, it's part of the command prompt (for non-first lines / first ones have have `>>>`, the followups `...`) in interactive python. I just clipped the whole session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing a collection while iterating can have (and in this case has) some unexpected consequences.

Your getter;

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    self.data.move_to_end(key)
    return super().__getitem__(key)
```

...moves the current key to the end of the collection, and that will make the for loop over `a.items` stop since it thinks it reached the end of the collection.

Commenting the `move_to_end` line allows the iteration to run as expected.

When you're iterating over `a.data.items`, your getter is never invoked so there it's not a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the very insightful answer!, however: after overriding the `__items__` method in the class as: `def __items__(self): return self.data.items()`, I still get the above symptoms (output). To my understanding, in this case the `QueueDict` getter is neither called, only that of `QueueDict.data`, which is the OrderedDict. Any ideas?

Comment: @ASz A breakpoint in `__items__()` seems to never be hit, I can't find documentation on that internal function, do you mean `__iter__()`?

Comment: Oh, damn, it is the simple `items()` method I have to override. I mixed `items()` up with `__iter__()` in my mental map. With overriding `def items(self): return self.data.items()` the for loop works as expected! Thank you, Joachim!